# Get Tweets with Fabric

Tags: java, android-studio, twitter-fabric

Can Anybody tell me how to get Tweets by using `fabric sdk`?

*I have* tried the official [link](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-tweets.html), but getting errors.

**So I need a way to use the code for Showing Tweets in different activity as I am already doing a lot in my MainActivity.**

*errors* are random like
"import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetViewFetchAdapter;" is depreciated.
no loop using import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Actually I have tried a lot of things so getting different errors

Regards.

Comment: "but getting errors." What errors are you encountering?

Comment: Please post the *actual* errors. "depreciated" is not a thing in Java, it is "deprecated".

Comment: I am a newbee so couldnot solve these one. Can you suggest me something thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have found out the way out.
We can do it in two ways either use Default fabric twitter adapter for timeline or make a custom adapter.

 Here, I am using the default way

```
final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
                    .screenName(userScreenName).build(); //creating user timeline

final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
 .setTimeline(userTimeline).build(); 

setListAdapter(adapter); //adapter for fetching tweets
```

NOTE: userScreenName can be fetched on successfull login.